Cut a given rod into segments of fixed sizes: wrong output
I am trying solve the CodingNinjas challenge Cut Into Segments:

You are given an integer ‘N’ denoting the length of the rod. You need to determine the maximum number of segments you can make of this rod provided that each segment should be of the length 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.

This is my code:
def cutSegments(n, x, y, z):
    if n == 0:
        return 0  # No segments needed for a rod of length 0
    if n < 0:
        return float('-inf')  # Or a very large negative number

    a = cutSegments(n - x, x, y, z) + 1
    b = cutSegments(n - y, x, y, z) + 1
    c = cutSegments(n - z, x, y, z) + 1
    ans = max(a, b, c)
    
    if ans>0:
        return ans
    else:
        return 0

print(cutSegments(8, 3, 3, 3))

The expected output for the given input is 0, as there is no way to cut 8 into segments of 3, but the output my code gives is 2. What is my mistake in this solution? Is there a way to make it work with recursion?

When all the recursive results are -inf, the if condition fails, so you return 0 instead of -inf. Then you add 1 to this. So you're essentially just calculating the recursion depth.

len([(i,j,k) for i in range(0, x+1) for  j in range(0, y+1) for k in range(0, z+1) if x*i + y*j + z*k ==n]) this would be probably a brute force solution which need correction

What output would you expect? What is the correct solution?

The problem is that when a deep recursive call returns -inf, you translate it to 0, and so the upper-level recursive calls will treat it as a success instead of a failure and add 1 to it.
The challenge is that 0 is a kind of success when n is 0, but when there is a constant failure (n < 0) you also need to eventually return 0.
To make this distinction, wrap your recursive function with another, simple function: only that wrapper function will translate -inf to 0:
def cutSegments(n, x, y, z):
    def recur(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n < 0:
            return float('-inf')         
        a = recur(n - x)
        b = recur(n - y)
        c = recur(n - z)
        return max(a, b, c) + 1  # don't replace -inf with 0 here
        
    res = recur(n)
    return 0 if res < 0 else res # ...only here!

Now it will work. Still, it is not very efficient. You could solve that with memoization. A simple implementation is by using functools.cache:
from functools import cache

def cutSegments(n, x, y, z):
    @cache
    def recur(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n < 0:
            return float('-inf')         
        a = recur(n - x)
        b = recur(n - y)
        c = recur(n - z)
        return max(a, b, c) + 1
        
    res = recur(n)
    return 0 if res < 0 else res

